# customized UIToolbar, using a background image of 480x44(points) becomes 480x88

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm creating an app, and I need to customize the UIToolBar which is located at the bottom.
My app supports ONLY landscape view.

1. The UIToolBar, which I added into storyboard, at the bottom of the screen, is 480x44
2. The background image, is 960x88 pixels

When I run it, the toolbar becomes 88 in height(the # of pixels).
Can anyone let me know if I missed something, or is doing it wrong?

Thanks!

Here's my code for the customization

```
- (void)customizeUIToolBar
{
    UIImage *toolBarImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"lower-menu.png"];

    [[UIToolbar appearance] setBackgroundImage:toolBarImage forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionBottom barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [[UIToolbar appearance] setBackgroundImage:toolBarImage forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionBottom barMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone];
}

- (void)customizeAppearance
{
    [self customizeUIToolBar];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [self customizeAppearance];

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add image with name lower-menu@2x.png in project. You are using image of retina display and testing on non-retina device. [Naming conventions blog](http://www.vigorouscoding.com/2012/03/naming-conventions-for-image-resources-in-ios/)

Comment: Hi, I copied the image to another @2x.png,dragged it into the project, and changed the code as below `UIImage *toolBarImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"lower-menu@2x.png"];` Didn't work...

Comment: btw, I am running on iPhone4S

Comment: Try this-[UIImage imageNamed:@"lower-menu"];

You should not specify @2x.

Comment: Hi, @Rahul, thanks, I tried it but it's still the same. I have both lower-menu.png and lower-menu@2x.png(which is a copy of the same image as lower-menu.png).

Comment: lower-menu.png should have size 480x44.

Comment: May be simulator you have selected is non-retina.Check it. Simulator -> Hardware->Device->

Comment: Hi, @Rahul, I just gave it a wild try, and it actually works on the phone, but wrong on the simulator.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Rahul! You got me!! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

> The UIToolBar, which I added into storyboard, at the bottom of the
>   screen, is 480x44

This 44 is in points. the actual size in pixels depends on the device you are using.

If its non-retina it would be of 44 pixels.

If its retina it would be of 88 pixels.

Comment: Hi, I'm supporting only retina display. However, I understood it as everything we see in storyboard, and programmatically, are points. How it shows it on the device, depends on the scaleFactor. Thus, I was expecting the toolbar at the bottom to be 44 in height.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing autolayout from `UIView` then it will not expand its height.

Comment: Thanks! But I tried unselecting "Autoresize Subviews" with the ToolBar, and then the super view, both didn't help.